# Getting an error "the application is incorrectly configured android" in game with Google Play Games

Tags: android, google-api, google-play-games

I have a Android game with Play Games SDK integrated (I'm using achievements and real-time multiplayer). I linked debug version of app (with debug key) and it worked just fine. But when I finished development and tried to link release version (singned with release key) of app it refused to link app with an error `"An error has occurred"` on step "Client ID Settings".

I checked project in Google Developer Console and there was multiple `Client ID` with the same (correct) `CERTIFICATE FINGERPRINT (SHA1)`. I tried to remove project in Developer Console but got an error: "Server error. Please try again". I removed all "Client IDs" and also game from "Game Services" and tried again but it didn't help.

Got same two errors:

1. First when trying to link app and create `"Client ID"`, just message `"An error has occurred"`. But it somehow creates multiple "Client ID" in GDConsole, but probably not links it to app.
2. Second when trying to remove project from Google Developer Console: `"Server error"`.

When I'm trying to sign in release version of app  shows an error: `"The application is incorrectly configured..."`. App Id, Certificate fingerprint and test account - everything ok.
Debug version works just fine.

I think it's some bug in Google Developer Console. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: 1. what key is used to sign release version of the app 2. did you use release key fingerprint for generete Client ID?

Comment: 1. release key used, fingerprint added correctly. 2. yes.
I see multiple "Client ID" in "Google Developer Console" under "Credentials" with the same correct release key fingerprint.

Comment: logcat also shows correct Package name, Cert SHA1 fingerprint, App Id

Comment: user also added to "Testing" list.